# Angular 6 - Switch between two components in main component

Tags: angular, routes

I have an app in Angular 6 and bootstrap. I have a main component, I want to be able to switch between two sub components in the main component but stay on the main component route. I have recreated here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xujgmw

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can define the proper routing for instance in `app-routing.module.ts` like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FormComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'detail',
        component: DetailsComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'policy',
        component: PolicyComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'detail',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in multiple ways.

1. Use routing: Define routes in your app module. Change the routes based on any event (for example , button click).
2. Use some flag to set which component is displayed. Update the flag and use `*ngIf` to show/hide component.
3. Use `*ngComponentOutlet` to render a component on UI.